# Why we can't assign lambda expression directly to reference variable of type Object?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I am doing some experiment with lambda expression and saw some behavior which I can't understand.

```
    Consumer consumer = (o1) -> {};
    Object obj1 = consumer; // this two line working fine
```

Above 2 lines of code does not complain anything as expected when I assign `consumer` to  `obj1`.

However when I tried to assign directly the lambda to object it started giving me a compilation error.

```
    Object obj2 = (o1) -> {}; // this line gives compilation error
```

The above line of code gives me an error :

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface.

My question is why we can't directly assign a lambda to a reference variable of type `Object`?

Edited: I have edited my question as there is a similar question already mentioned but my question main goal was to ensure why `Object o1 = "Hello"` will work but not the lambda.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Thanks!!! However, I was wondering how Object o1 = "Hello" works but lambda expression can work in the same way but now it is clear.

Comment: I would recommend deletion of this Question @Amit!

Comment: The duplicate question mentioned here not that much clear to me like if Object o1 = "Hello"; works in java why not the lambda.

Comment: I assume you are using [`java.util.function.Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)? If so, please be aware that you are using a [raw type, which you should always avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: @Turing85 You are right and thanks for your suggestion. That was just for testing code that's why I had not put generic type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you assign a lambda expression to a variable of type `Object`, the compiler has no idea which functional interface this lambda expression should implement.

For example, the lambda expression `o -> o.toString ()` can be assigned to either a `Consumer` or a `Function`:

```
Consumer<String> cons = o -> o.toString ();
Function<String,String> cons2 = o -> o.toString ();
```

Therefore you have to either assign the lambda expression to a variable of a functional interface type or to cast the lambda expression to some functional interface type before assigning it to the `Object` variable.

Comment: Thanks now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java compiler uses a property type to recognize fields of an anonymous class the lambda denotes.
According to [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) a lambda is just a convenient approach to denote anonymous classes with a lone method and create the objects of the classes. The Object class has more methods, and it is a class. Lambdas are used along with interfaces.